# Verify existence in database? (MySql & ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

how can i verify if an element is already in my database, when trying to add a new element into the same database?

i know it might need some sql code and i can't do what i want to do:

this is the full code of the button:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
    {
        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        //saves files in the disk
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/" + FileName));
        //add an entry to the database
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnString"].ConnectionString;

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strConnString);
        string strQuery = "insert into testingdb.country (Relation, FileName, FilePath) values (@Relation, @FileName, @FilePath)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strQuery);

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Relation", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "images/" + FileName);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("images/" + FileName)))
            {
                Response.Write("El Objeto ya existe en la base de datos.");
            }
            else
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }
}
```

How can it be done? i'm kinda new using ASP.NET and MySql connections/commands.

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: The verification of the "File.Exists" inside the "try", doesn't work, i need to verify if an object in the database exists.

Comment: Have you're configuring path properly? Usually `Server.MapPath` uses virtual path e.g. `File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + FileName))`.

Comment: tried it, same result, no message & no object added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Already figured an answer, all i had to do was to write the FileName outside the MapPath() method, like this:

```
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("images/") + FileName))
{
    //mycode & Blah, Blah, Blah.
}
```